# Заголовок кадра и назначение его полей

Tags: ethernet

Уже довольно продолжительное время долблюсь в один и тот же вопрос и не могу на него ответить (точнее, мои ответы признаются неверными, но я не могу понять, что не так).

Заголовок состоит из адреса получателя, адреса отправителя и типа кадра. Вопрос состоит в том, для чего указаны эти поля и как их использует/обрабатывает драйвер устройства (допустим, того, который перехватил данный кадр).

С типом вроде все понятно, он нужен для того, чтобы принимающая программа знала, как обработать содержимое кадра в зависимости от его типа.

Адрес получателя - используется как идентификатор для предполагаемого получателя. Драйвер устройства, как я понимаю, принимает IP-адрес, сравнивает его с MAC-адресом устройства и, если они коррелированы, то кадр принимается.

Но вот вопрос, что по поводу адреса отправителя. У меня были предположения, что он необходим для обратной связи с отправителем, для отправки другому устройству уведомления о том, что кадр получен, может, для идентификации отправителя. Но все это оказалось неверным.

И то, как именно драйвер Ethernet обрабатывает поля SA и DA, мне тоже неясно, к сожалению.

Надеюсь, что хоть кто-то мне это разъяснит, а то уже идей нет.

P.S. В интернетах очень много информации о адресе получателя, но об адресе отправителя найти что-то не удалось.

Comment: Адрес отправителя, безесловно, нужен для формирования ответа. (а IP с MAC никто не сравнивает, это разные домены адресов). Вообще же, мне кажется, что  для того, чтобы **хорошо разобраться**,  вам нужно начать с [OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI), не забыть почитать по ссылочкам оттуда и обратить особое внимание на [IP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP) и  [ARP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP). После этого можно будет конкретно ответить на то, что осталось непонятным.

Comment: @avp Понял, ошибся (с MAC и IP). Большую часть того, что есть на вики на этот счет, я уже читал. И то, что он нужен для формирования ответа, тоже. Однако преподаватель упорно говорит, что это чушь, и SA нужен не для этого -.-

Да и я нигде не смог найти, как именно драйвер обращается с этим адресом (в общих чертах, как я понял, при совпадении адреса получателя  и адреса устройства, получатель формирует ответ со своим физ и лог адресом и отправляет обратно отправителю, ставшему получателем?).

Comment: Интересный вопрос.  Я посмотрел поподробней и вижу, что и в ARP и в DHCP source MAC  передается в данных пакета. (в принципе это позволяет делать запрос от третьего лица, используется это реально или нет, не знаю). Посмотрим, может кто-то знает более подробно и ответит.